# Shuffling names (strings) without repetition in C

Tags: shuffle

Suppose I have twelve names of students. I wanna randomly create 4 teams containing three members each.

For instance, The names are:

1. Niko
2. Jacob
3. Roman
4. Vlad
5. Corvo
6. Daud
7. Hitman
8. Harry
9. Ron
10. Fred
11. George
12. Dimitri

The output I want is like

Niko,Ron,Corvo.

Jacob,Daud,Harry.

Vlad,Hitman,Fred.

George,Dimitri,Roman.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Give number to each name ,which you have already given :)
use rand() a standard c library function to generate random number .
So generate 3 random numbers(if repeated number came you can ignore it) at once